# CSRF TOKEN MISTATCH LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, csrf

I am facing CSRF token mismatch problem in laravel. I have checked all notes from stackflow and other sites also but not able to clear this problem.

https://mybestlife.mg-wellness.com/admin/login

user : admin@gmail.com
pass : 1234

you can check the error in console.

---

### Ajax

```js
$("#loginform").on('submit', function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  $('button.submit-btn').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.alert-info').show();
  $('.alert-info p').html('Authenticating...');

  $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:$(this).prop('action'),
      data:new FormData(this),
      headers: headers,
      dataType:'JSON',
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          if ((data.errors)) {
              $('.alert-success').hide();
              $('.alert-info').hide();
              $('.alert-danger').show();
              $('.alert-danger ul').html('');
              for(var error in data.errors) {
                  $('.alert-danger p').html(data.errors[error]);
              }
          } else {
              // console.log(data)
              $('.alert-info').hide();
              $('.alert-danger').hide();
              $('.alert-success').show();
              $('.alert-success p').html('Success !');
              window.location.href = data;
          }
          $('button.submit-btn').prop('disabled',false);
      }
  });
});
```

---

### Login function

```php
public function doLogin(Request $request)
{
    // print_r($request->all());
    $rules = [
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
    
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
    }
    //--- Validation Section Ends
    
    // Attempt to log the user in
    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'status' => 1,
        'role' => 1,
        'level' => 0
    ], $request->remember)) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
        return response()->json(route('dashboard'));
    }
    
    // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
    return response()->json(array('errors' => [
        0 => 'Credentials Doesn\'t Match !'
    ]));    
}
```

Code is working perfectly on localhost and my testing server. But not on the server, i shared above.
Please help me to over come this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Check your production server time. It may be out of sync

Comment: can you post htaccess file code

Comment: i can see for token is generating every request so its throwing error .try to restart server or check htaccess file  or disabled  cookie etc..

Comment: htaccess code 
https://mybestlife.mg-wellness.com/htaccess_code.txt

Comment: is server disabled cookie ?

Comment: no i don't think so

Comment: Turn off debug mode for your site/remove the link. As things stand the contents of your .env file are visible.

Comment: @IGP thanks i disabled debug mode and hide the .env file.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is honestly. But aside from that, your .env file is still exposed if you navigate to yourwebsite.com/.env

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a header. That's how I've always passed the CSRF token when I use ajax.

The following should be in your `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file.

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
});
```

When trying to login using your site, I couldn't see the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header in the request.

---

I think you didn't set the `APP_URL`'s value correctly. It should be
`APP_URL=https://mybestlife.mg-wellness.com` instead of what you currently have. (`APP_URL=http://localhost/mybestlife_mg_wellness/`)

(run `php artisan config:clear` after changing `.env` file)

Your site has debug mode on and an unrelated error about the route `'user_login'` not existing, this exposes your whole configuration. Please take care to update your database credentials, they are **compromised**.

This is very important.

Also, rerun the command `php artisan key:generate` to update the `APP_KEY` as well.

Comment: var headers = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}

It is already there sir

Comment: Okay, I think I know what it is. I'll edit the answer

Comment: All done locally and uploaded again. Still same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `@csrf`  in your form

```
<form  method="post" action="javascript:void(0)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf 
</form>
```

also add header in jquery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
               headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
           });
```

also add this meta tag in head of page

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then you will never get token error .

Comment: you have to provide your form also whats the error all things you have to add then i will help you to get your solution

Comment: this is the form https://mybestlife.mg-wellness.com/admin/login and error is coming in console.
Need anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a below line in data array

```
 data:{
    _token : {{csrf_field()}},
     
     name:name
  }
```